# Copy and rename an wildcard image file c#

Tags: c#, windows, copy, rename, wildcard

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to copy and rename an image file(.png). The copying process is working. **But the copy should be named "OUTPUT.png" and not use the old name or any parts of it**.

**Important edit:**
The old/original file name is not known, because it is created randomly.

I'd appreciate your help, thoughts, etc.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sourceDir = @"C:\Users\booth\Documents\190604_avee_1.4\Files\Snapshots";
    string backupDir = @"C:\Users\booth\Documents\190604_avee_1.4\Files";

    try
    {
        string[] picList = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.png");

        foreach (string f in picList)
        {

            string fName = f.Substring(sourceDir.Length + 1);
   File.Copy(@"C:\Users\booth\Documents\190604_avee_1.4\Files\Snapshots\*.png", @"C:\Users\booth\Documents\190604_avee_1.4\Files\OUTPUT.png");
        }

        foreach (string f in picList)
        {
            File.Delete(f);
        }
    }

    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException dirNotFound)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dirNotFound.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to find the name of the file with getfiles or enumerate files, and then use those names to do the copy

Comment: @BugFinder  the copying already works. But the created copy is not renamed to OUTPUT.png. How can i get that done?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your Copy call should be using the fName var that you create the line before? Trying to copy a wildcard filename when you have a var with the file name in it seems impractical. So something like `File.Copy(@"[insert path]\"+fName, ...)` should work, right?

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm not sure to be honest. I'll try that. I just want the copy to be renamed to "OUTPUT.png"

Answer (score 0):

Now if your purpose is to copy the .png ones from the corresponding folder to the other folder and then delete the images, this code will do the trick.

```
 using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Udemyvericekme
    {
        public partial class opera : Form
        {
            public opera()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string sourceDir = @"C:\Users\Ebubekir\Desktop\resimler\";
                string backupDir = @"C:\Users\Ebubekir\Desktop\bekrabackup\";

                try
                {
                    string[] picList = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.png");

                    foreach (string f in picList)
                    {

                        string fName = f.Substring(sourceDir.Length + 1);
                        try
                        {
                            File.Copy(f, backupDir + fName);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (string f in picList)
                    {
                        File.Delete(f);
                    }
                }

                catch (DirectoryNotFoundException dirNotFound)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dirNotFound.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your response. The Copying process is working meanwhile. But i want the created copy to be named "OUTPUT.png". How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Udemyvericekme
{
    public partial class opera : Form
    {
        public opera()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sourceDir = @"C:\Users\Ebubekir\Desktop\resimler\";
            string backupDir = @"C:\Users\Ebubekir\Desktop\bekrabackup\";

            try
            {
                string[] picList = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.png");

                foreach (string f in picList)
                {

                    string fName = f.Substring(sourceDir.Length + 1);
                    try
                    {
                        File.Copy(f, backupDir + "OUTPUT" + fName);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }

                foreach (string f in picList)
                {
                    File.Delete(f);
                }
            }

            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException dirNotFound)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dirNotFound.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}


 File.Copy(f, backupDir + "OUTPUT" + fName);
```

You just change it here

Comment: I've tried it a couple of times now, with a file called 11.png. Copy is renamed to "FilesOUTPUT11.png".

Comment: Didn't we want to do that ?

Comment: it should be renamed to "OUTPUT.png"

Comment: Do you know how to do that? Only thing i saw is File.Move method... But therefore i would need the original file name and that is not possible, because it is randomnly created through a snapshot program